# HTML5: Play local video from iPad camera roll

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, video, ios6

I found this SO post, but it is out of date: [Play a local video from iPad in an HTML 5 webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924711/play-a-local-video-from-ipad-in-an-html-5-webpage)

With iOS 6 came the ability to access the camera roll for uploading a file (e.g., .mov files captured from iPad camera). I am not sure who to give credit to, but I found a jsFiddle that uses an input field to grab a local file and load it into the video element for playback. This works on the desktop accept for .mov files, but removing "video/*" from the accept attribute allows the input file to select a .mov from local, and forcing the file.type to "video/mp4" in the JS allows the .mov to play in the video element.

See jsFiddle referenced above: http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/embedded/result,js,html,css/presentation/

However, when it comes to this working in mobile safari the file still fails to load, even though you see a preview thumbnail and file name in the file input field. I added a link to the page concatenating "?dl=1" to the blob: url, but clicking it just results in mSafari saying “invalid address” even though a link to a hosted .mov plays in quicktime. Ultimately, I want to be able to select a video from the camera roll, play it in an html video player, and (ideally) store the source path of that file in a db to be accessed at a later time. What piece am I missing?

See my edited version of the jsFiddle working here:
http://lt.umn.edu/email/

JS:

```
playSelectedFile = function playSelectedFileInit(event) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    //var type = file.type;
    var type = "video/mp4";
    var videoNode = document.querySelector('video');
    var canPlay = videoNode.canPlayType(type);
    canPlay = (canPlay === '' ? 'no' : canPlay);

    var message = 'Can play type "' + type + '": ' + canPlay;
    var isError = canPlay === 'no';
    //displayMessage(message, isError);

    if (isError) {
        return;
    }

    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    var tempURL = fileURL+'?dl=1';
    var tempText = '<a href="'+tempURL+'?dl=1">'+tempURL+'?dl=1</a>';
    displayMessage(tempText, isError);

    videoNode.src = fileURL;
}
```

Comment: No. However, the new features inside iOS8 do appear to possibly allow some form of solution. We will see!

Answer (score 0):

Use `var videoNode = document.querySelector('video')[0];` when using querySelector

EDIT:

Otherwise try to remove the video node and create it again with the right src. I had the same problem, that the movie wont play. I guess changing the src wont work everywhere..

Comment: David, thank you for responding! I tried using [0] as you suggested, but that didn't really effect iOS playback. It also caused the JS not to work on a desktop. What are you referring to in your EDIT when you said to try removing the video node and creating it again with the right src? Where is the right source if the one I am using is not already the right one?

Comment: the source might be correct. I dont know if it will work but i noticed that changing the src of a html5 video on iOS wont work, youll have to remove the whole tag and create it on the fly with the right src. Then add a play on top of that to start the video automaticly.

Comment: I did as you suggested and removed the current video element before replacing it with a new video element containing a src attribute with the newest path, but it still fails. [The code that now works as you suggested is here](http://lt.umn.edu/email/index2.html) if you view source. I thought for sure you had the solution!

Comment: Interestingly, [caniuse.com/#search=createObjectURL](http://caniuse.com/#search=createObjectURL) shows that the current version of iOS Safari (I have 6.1.3) supports Blobs so theoretically this should work... unless iOS Safari is not generating a blob that can point to the source file correctly?